# My App waiting for debugger in release mode in android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, facebook-login, android-debug

I am an amateur in Kotlin and android studio. I am trying to integrate the facebook login to my app but end up at a roadblock. After following the facebook login for android integration tutorial, I am unable to run the app in release mode. I did previously run the same app in debug mode for debugging. But now the app on my phone says "Waiting for Debugger" in release mode too.

I have done the following already and it has not worked.

1. Set debuggable to false in release mode
2. Restart ADB
3. Restart Android Studio
4. Restart phone
5. Restart Computer
6. Switch USB port
7. Update everything
8. moving the keystore inside the base path of my android project.
9. set minifyEnabled false
10. Tried Checking BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("debug")

In the `Run` it shows,

```
07/24 12:11:43: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.vishwa.imaginators/com.example.vishwa.imaginators.SplashscreenActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 16495 on device xiaomi-redmi_note_3-57c506ac
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.vishwa.imaginators is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
```

I did not put up the `logcat`  because it's got tons of text in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have added your app in `Select app to be debugged` on your phone. In `Settings -> Developer Options -> Select app to be debugged`

To resolve this, go to **Select app to be debugged** and click on `No apps`

Comment: I did not find "Select app to be debugged" option in the menu. Can you please tell where it is? or Are you referring to the as told by @Hemant Parmar

Comment: @Eswar no. Its on the phone. You can go to phone settings as indicated in my answer

Comment: But I would not want to be doing this every time, for every app. I did have this problem previously. This only suggests that I'll have to do it every time I hit the run button?

Comment: @Eswar its one time thing

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: It worked as a one time thing. I think it was selected before but accidentally sometime I deselected it.

Answer (score 1):

Restart android studio and than check, if not fix than On some **machines/projects** the debugger do not attach automatically so you need to attach it manually.

**(studio menu -> Run -> Attach debugger to Android process)**

make sure you set debuggable true in release mode:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false  
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but every time I hit the run button, it throws the waiting for debugger on launching activity and then I have to attach the debugger to the process. Is there a way I can avoid doing this every time. Previous to adding the facebook login, I did not have such problems.

Comment: make it `debuggable false`

Comment: are you run app by debug mode ?

Comment: I am not running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the phone keeps waiting for debugger, I restarted the phone and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened in My emulator,then i solved this by kill the emulator.After i run it again then it works perfectly.